How can I compute the limit with an integral？
I came across a problem that I couldn't solve in a mathematical analysis textbook：

Let $\alpha, L \in \mathbb{R}$ and $L \neq 0$:
$$
\mbox{If}\quad\lim_{n \to \infty}
\dfrac{\displaystyle n^{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n}\sin\left(x\right)\,
\mathrm{d}x}{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n}\cos\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x} = L,\quad\mbox{then find}\quad\alpha, L
$$

My attempt：Let $a_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \sin x \mathrm{~d} x$，$b_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \cos x \mathrm{~d} x$,then we get
\begin{aligned}
    a_n&=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \mathrm{~d} (\cos x)=-x^n\cos x\big |_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^{n-1} \cos x \mathrm{~d} x=nb_{n-1}\\
    b_n&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n  \mathrm{~d} (\sin x)=x^n\sin x\big |_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^{n-1} \sin x \mathrm{~d} x=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n}-na_{n-1}\\
    &=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n}-n(n-1)b_{n-2}.
\end{aligned}
But the subsequent iterations were so complex that I couldn't figure out the answer. Are there any other ideas to solve this problem?

are you preparing for jee advanced? seems like a fiitjee question

@Mathslover sorry,i never  know  the jee advanced before you say it.

where did you find that question? which textbook

@Mathslover a Chinese math textbook.

Context: JEE = Joint Entrance Examination - "The Joint Entrance Examination (JEE) is an engineering entrance assessment conducted for admission to various engineering colleges in India."

The title ought to be more specific.

We have: $$a_n=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \sin x \mathrm{~d} x,\ b_n=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \cos x \mathrm{~d} x$$
$$a_n=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \mathrm{~d} (\cos x)=-x^n\cos x\bigg |_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^{n-1} \cos x \mathrm{~d} x=nb_{n-1}$$
So, we have to compute the limit: $L=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^\alpha a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^{\alpha+1}b_{n-1}}{b_n}$ for some $\alpha$.
We can simplify $b_n$ as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}b_n=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \cos x \mathrm{~d} x&=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac\pi2-x\right)^n \cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right) \mathrm{~d} x\qquad \text{Property of definite integral}\\&=\frac\pi2\int_0^1\left(\frac\pi2-\frac{\pi t}2\right)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}2\right)\mathrm{~d} t
\qquad \text{Substitute } x=\frac{\pi t}2\\&=\left(\frac\pi2\right)^{n+1}\int_0^1(1-t)^n\left(\frac{\pi t}2+O(t^3)\right)\mathrm{~d} t\qquad \text{Series expansion; Big O notation}\\&=\left(\frac\pi2\right)^{n+1}\left(\dfrac\pi2\operatorname B(n+1,2)+O\left(\operatorname B(n+1,4)\right)\right)\qquad \text{Beta function}\\&=\left(\frac\pi2\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac\pi2\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(n+3)}+O\left(\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(4)}{\Gamma(n+5)}\right)\right)\qquad \text{Relationship to gamma function}\\&=\left(\frac\pi2\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac\pi2\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)\qquad\text{Since }\Gamma(n+1)=n!\end{aligned}$$
Now,
$$\dfrac{n^{\alpha+1}b_{n-1}}{b_n}=n^{\alpha+1}\dfrac{2}\pi\frac{\frac\pi2\frac1{n(n+1)}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)}{\frac\pi2\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)}=n^{\alpha+1}\left(\frac2\pi\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{n(n+1)}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)$$
For the convergence of the limit to a positive number, we need to set $\alpha+1=0$, i.e., $\boxed{\alpha=-1}$. Hence, the required limit is $\boxed{L=\dfrac2\pi}$.
Hope this helps!

We have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^n\sin x \,\mathrm{d} x \le \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n \,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{(\pi/2)^{n+1}}{n+1}. \tag{1}$$
We have, for all $n \ge 4$,
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n\sin x \,\mathrm{d} x &\ge \int_{\pi/2 - 2/\sqrt{n}}^{\pi/2} x^n\sin x \,\mathrm{d} x \\
 &\ge \sin(\pi/2 - 2/\sqrt{n})\int_{\pi/2 - 2/\sqrt{n}}^{\pi/2} x^n \,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &= \frac{(\pi/2)^{n+1}\cos \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}{n + 1}
 - \frac{(\pi/2-2/\sqrt{n})^{n+1}\cos \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}{n + 1}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Using $\sin x \le x$
for all $x\ge 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n\cos x\, \mathrm{d} x
 &= \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n \sin(\pi/2 - x)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &\le \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n (\pi/2 - x)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &= \frac{(\pi/2)^{n+2}}{(n+2)(n+1)}. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Using IBP, we have, for all $n\ge 4$,
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n\cos x\, \mathrm{d} x
 &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\sin x\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &\ge \int_{\pi/2 - 2/\sqrt{n}}^{\pi/2} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\sin x\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &\ge \sin(\pi/2 - 2/\sqrt{n})\int_{\pi/2 - 2/\sqrt{n}}^{\pi/2} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &= \frac{(\pi/2)^{n+2}\cos\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}{(n+2)(n+1)}
 - \frac{(\pi/2- 2/\sqrt{n})^{n+2}\cos\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}{(n+2)(n+1)}.\tag{4}
\end{align*}
Using (1) and (4), we have, for all $n\ge 4$,
\begin{align*}
 \frac{n^\alpha \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n\sin x\,\mathrm{d} x}{\int_0^{\pi/2} x^n\cos x\, \mathrm{d} x}
 &\le n^\alpha\cdot \frac{\frac{(\pi/2)^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{(\pi/2)^{n+2}\cos\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}{(n+2)(n+1)}
  - \frac{(\pi/2- 2/\sqrt{n})^{n+2}\cos\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}{(n+2)(n+1)}}\\[10pt] 
 &= \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{n^\alpha (n + 2)}{\cos \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}
 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \left(1 - \frac{4}{\pi \sqrt{n}}\right)^{n+2}}.\tag{5}
\end{align*}
Using (2) and (3), we have, for all $n\ge 4$,
\begin{align*}
 \frac{n^\alpha \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n\sin x\,\mathrm{d} x}{\int_0^{\pi/2} x^n\cos x\, \mathrm{d} x}
 &\ge n^\alpha\cdot \frac{\frac{(\pi/2)^{n+1}\cos \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}{n + 1}
  - \frac{(\pi/2-2/\sqrt{n})^{n+1}\cos \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}{n + 1}}{\frac{(\pi/2)^{n+2}}{(n+2)(n+1)}}\\[10pt]
 &= \frac{2}{\pi}n^\alpha(n+2)\cos\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot 
 \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{4}{\pi \sqrt{n}}\right)^{n+1}\right).\tag{6}
\end{align*}
From (5) and (6), using $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 - \frac{4}{\pi \sqrt{n}})^{n+1}= \lim_{n\to \infty}(1 - \frac{4}{\pi \sqrt{n}})^{n+2} = 0$, using the squeeze theorem, we have $\alpha = -1$, and $L = \frac{2}{\pi}$.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \mbox{Find}\ \alpha\ \mbox{and}\ L\ \mbox{such that}
\\[2mm] & \color{#44f}{\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\ds{n^{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n}\sin\pars{x}\,\dd x} \over \ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n}\cos\pars{x}\,\dd x}} = L,\quad\mbox{with}\quad
\left\{\substack{\ds{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}\\[2mm]
\ds{L \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{0}}}\right.}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
& \mbox{Note that}\
\\ & \color{red}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n}\expo{\ic x}\dd x} \sr{x\ \mapsto\ \pi/2 - x}{=}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\pars{{\pi \over 2} - x}^{n}
\expo{\ic\pars{\pi/2 - x}}\,\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
\pars{\pi \over 2}^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{1 -{2 \over \pi}x}}
\bracks{\sin\pars{x} + \ic\cos\pars{x}}\,\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \overbrace{\sr{{\rm as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}
\pars{\pi \over 2}^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-2nx/\pi}\,\pars{x + \ic}\,\,\dd x}
^{\ds{Laplace's\ Method}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\color{red}{\pars{\pi \over 2}^{n}
\bracks{\pars{\pi \over 2n}^{2} + {\pi \over 2n}\ic}}
\\[5mm] \implies & \
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n}\sin\pars{x}\,\dd x}
& \ds{\sr{{\rm as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}} &
\ds{\pars{\pi \over 2}^{n}{\pi \over 2n}}
\\
\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n}\cos\pars{x}\,\dd x}
& \ds{\sr{{\rm as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}} &
\ds{\pars{\pi \over 2}^{n}\pars{\pi \over 2n}^{2}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\ds{n^{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n}\sin\pars{x}\,\dd x} \over \ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n}\cos\pars{x}\,\dd x}}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{\alpha}{\pars{\pi/2}^{n}\ \bracks{\pi/\pars{2n}} \over \pars{\pi/2}^{n}\ \bracks{\pi/\pars{2n}}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{2 \over \pi}\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{\alpha + 1}}}
\ \mbox{with}\
\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{\alpha + 1} =
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{0} & \mbox{if} & \ds{\alpha} & \ds{<} & \ds{-1}
\\
\ds{\large 1} & {\large\mbox{if}} & \ds{\large\alpha} & \ds{=} & \ds{\large -1}
\\
\ds{\infty} & \mbox{if} & \ds{\alpha} & \ds{>} & \ds{-1}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm] & \mbox{The solution, with}\ L\ \mbox{finite and}\ \not= 0,\ \mbox{is obviously}
\end{align}
$$
\bbx{\color{#44f}{L = {2 \over \pi}\quad
\color{black}{\mbox{with}}\quad \alpha = - 1}}
$$

Here's yet another way of approaching the problem. I must admit it's not as rigorous as some of the other answers, and fixing that may not be very easy. Still, I managed to use a trick that is quite different from the other answers, and I wanted to share that.
We can start just as the OP did, finding that we need to calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n^{\alpha} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$. Since $a_n = nb_{n-1}$, we may replace $b_n$ with $\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}$ to get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n^{\alpha}(n+1) \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$. Our main problem is to find how $a_n/a_{n+1}$ behaves as $n$ goes to infinity.
We have $a_n := \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} x^n \sin x\,dx.$ Now let's define the function $A(z) := \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$. Here $z$ is a variable whose only job is to keep the different $a_n$'s apart; it has no other meaning. We get
$$A(z) = \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} dx\,\sin x \sum_{n=0}^\infty (xz)^n = \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin x\,dx}{1 - xz}.$$
This may look like it's completely missing the point, but here comes the trick. We realize that for any $|z|<2/\pi$, the integral will converge, but as soon as we put $z = 2/\pi$, it becomes divergent. From that we conclude that $z = 2/\pi$ is a singularity of $A(z)$, and there is no singularity closer to zero than that.
Hence, the power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges for all $|z| < 2/\pi$, and $2/\pi$ is its radius of convergence $R$. Due to the well-known ratio test, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = R = \frac{2}{\pi}.$$
So in the original expression $(n+1)n^\alpha \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$, the ratio goes to $2/\pi$ in the limit, so for the expression to have a nonzero finite limit, we must choose $\alpha = -1$. Then, we have $\frac{n+1}{n} \to 1$ and the limit is $2/\pi$.
